# VBA executes on 1 machine but not another

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a series of macro's to create a daily report. One of these macro's is a simple one liner that copies data from one sheet to another within the same workbook. The problem is that it works on one machine but not another. The machines are both intel based machines running the same OS version and the same MS Office version and exactly the same data set. The only difference is one is a 32 bit machine where the other is a 64 bit. Wondering if anyone has any idea to either work around this or can articulate why this would be happening. The script looks like this:

```
Sub Copy_S3ToS1()
'
' Select everything from Sheet3 and copy to Sheet1
'
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
'
End Sub
```

See - very simple. I do not understand why it works on one machine and not the other.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? That can describe any number of things from throwing an error, to not compiling, to crashing the computer, to starting a fire, etc.

Comment: Also, what is 32/64 bit? the OS or Office or both?  but either way, it doesn't make any sense unless it's just yelling at you because of a reference error.

Comment: In termsof it not working, it does not error out or anything like that. It seems to go through the motions, but when I go to the destination sheet, the data that was supposed to have been copied is not there.

Comment: As far as what is 32/64 bit - the OS primarily. The Office suite loaded matches the OS - meaning 64 bit office on 64 bit os and 32 on 32

Comment: You sure you do not have some cell way down column A that has data in it and the paste is happening way down the sheet?

Comment: @jtk001 -  Add a line right before the line in your example that does the copying: `MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)`. Then run the code again. It should stop pop up a message box showing what it's calculating as the  destination.  What does it say? Is it correct?

Comment: @jtk001 - also, you haven't included enough code to be meaningful. (See here how to create a **[mcve]**.)  Are you, by chance, using `On Error Resume Next` somewhere?

Comment: The pop-up is empty.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about this not being enough code. It works just fine on my other machine.

Comment: How about - `MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address & vbLf & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address` ?

Comment: So the ranges returned are correct. The range to copy on sheet3 are A1:G12978 and used range on sheet1 are A1:G11903. The dialogue box shows on two separate lines A1:G12978 & A1:G11903. Ultimately I am trying to copy the info in Sheet3 A1:G12978 into Sheet1 starting at A11904 (appending the data in sheet 1.

Comment: The data changes daily so I cannot use a fixed range - and as I mentioned earlier, this works flawlessly on another machine. I just cannot figure out why it doesn't work here.

Comment: There is another part of the macro tree where I have had to introduce wait periods to make other parts work. Is it possible there is a timing issue?

Comment: I can share the entire macro tree if that would help

Comment: Does the sub work when run by itself, without any other code?

Comment: yes it does - on the machine that works... I have determined it is something with this particular machine somehow. I used a third machine with the exact same OS and MS Office version. It works on that machine as well... There is something here I need to figure out

Comment: I found a way around the issue. I created a script that called the copy and paste functions in separate lines with a time delay. A little less elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by separating the copy and paste functions and adding a delay timer.

```
Sub Copy_S3ToS1()
    '
    ' Select everything from Sheet3 and copy to Sheet1
    '
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A").Activate
    SendKeys "{down}"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```